# Which lego set or theme are the following pieces part of?

Tags: set-identification

I bought these second hand so don't even know if they belong together. The main colors are orange and white.
Definitely a piece has big orange wheels. Similar to the buggy in the Neptune carrier from the Atlantis theme but in orange.

I have also a minifigure in a grey and white helmet. He is sitting in a white orange flying base.

And I've got a part of a set where a green weird figure is captured on a kind of white stretcher.

Who can help me identify this set?